# Bottom Navigation does not work and leads to app crash

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I have tried to use Bottom Navigation on my application but it doesn't work and application keep crash.
here is my main activity:

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            loadFragment(new HomeFragment());
            BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
            navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.homePage:
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;

                case R.id.chat:
                    fragment = new ChatFragment();
                    break;
            }

            return loadFragment(fragment);
        }

        private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            if (fragment != null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                        .commit();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and here is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:text="@string/title_home"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

also, I create a two fragment for the navigation, both have the same xml and class code

the fragment xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the  fragment class :

```
package com.example.testing;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);

    }
}
```

Also I have added this code to my build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

BUT here what I got in my logcat :

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2019-04-05 21:55:34.150 3169-3169/com.example.testing E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testing, PID: 3169
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testing/com.example.testing.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.testing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler chat in class com.example.testing.MainActivity
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:254)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:482)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:530)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:206)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:128)
        at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(BottomNavigationView.java:252)
        at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:187)
2019-04-05 21:55:34.152 3169-3169/com.example.testing E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:114)
            ... 26 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: chat [interface android.view.MenuItem]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2068)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:250)
            ... 33 more
```

PLEASE HELP

HERE is the menu xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:id="@+id/chat"
        android:icon="@drawable/chaticon"
        android:onClick="chat"
        android:title="" />


    <item android:id="@+id/homePage"
        android:icon="@drawable/homeicon"
        android:onClick="homepage"
        android:title="" />


</menu>
```

Comment: Can you please include the menu XML

Comment: Also check if there are any errors in your activity xml (around line 20 - the bottomNav)

Comment: line 20 which is this line :     <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
 I do not why its cause an error

Comment: Remove the `onClick` attributes from the menu `<item>`s.

Comment: yeeeeees it is work ; thank you so much

Comment: Check my answer. I believe it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line in your menu XML file -

```
android:onClick="chat"
```

This is trying to refer to a method `public void chat(View)` which will handle the click event of your menu item. However, there's no such method defined in your activity and the app crashes as it can't find a method which it expects to find. Same with the other menu item except it crashed before it could even reach that.

The solution? Since you've already implemented an OnClick for the bottom navigation menu, remove the `onClick` attribute from the menu items.

Comment: @user11211222 please upvote and accept if this solved your issue

Comment: @user11211222 Please accept it as answer. It will remove the question from the unanswered queue and you will even get 2 reputation for accepting the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

`Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler chat in class com.example.testing.MainActivity`

Remove onclicks

Comment: What is chat listener? Where is it?

Comment: Ha, delete all onclicks from menu items

Comment: That's not really helpful I believe. You're just giving some general purpose tips to solve some issues. But the question here has provided specific details about a specific issue. This answer might solve some issues but is not relevant here

Comment: And add titles, better to fill them with some text

Comment: ok. Your comments may be helpful. You should edit your answer to include them instead